# Ruby 2.3 - not comprehensible ArgumentError exception

Tags: ruby, keyword-argument

I'm currently in the process of upgrading a project from ruby 1.9.3 to ruby 2.3.0 and there is one thing I can't wrap my head around concerning keyword arguments.

I have a method definition like so:

```
def icon(icon_name, opts = {})
  # ...
end
```

I call that method like so:

```
icon(:info, class: 'info-popup', data: { content: 'content', variation: 'inverted' })
```

and get the exception

```
unknown keywords: class, data
```

So I looked at the documentation of method calling in ruby 2.3 and read up on keyword arguments and tried the following things:

```
def icon(icon_name, opts: {}); end
icon(:info, opts: { class: 'info-popup', data: { content: object.description, variation: 'inverted' } }
#=> unknown keyword: opts

def icon(icon_name, *+args); end
icon(:info, class: 'info-popup', data: { content: 'content', variation: 'inverted' })
#=> unknown keywords: class, data

def icon(icon_name, *opts, **_); end
icon(:info, class: 'info-popup', data: { content: 'content', variation: 'inverted' })
#=> unknown keywords: class, data

def icon(icon_name, class: nil, data: nil); end
icon(:info, class: 'info-popup', data: { content: 'content', variation: 'inverted' })
#=> unknown keywords: class, data
```

What am I missing here?

Also, to give a little perspective: I would like to call that icon method in many different ways, since underneath there can be many options used like `size: :small`, or `disabled: true`, etc. resulting in according CSS classes. So the minimum way of calling the method is `icon(:name_of_icon)`, which means setting a hundred keyword params with `nil` as default value seems not very practical to me...

**UPDATE**

This is part of a rails project, and the method is defined in a `SemanticHelper` module. Inside the method looks like this:

```
def icon(icon_name, opts = {})
  additional_classes = ''

  # STATES
  additional_classes << 'disabled ' if !!opts.delete(:disabled)

  # VARIATIONS
  additional_classes << 'circular '   if !!opts.delete(:circular)
  additional_classes << 'square '     if !!opts.delete(:square)
  additional_classes << 'inverted '   if !!opts.delete(:inverted)
  additional_classes << 'basic '      if !!opts.delete(:basic)
  additional_classes << 'link icon '  if !!opts.delete(:link)

  additional_classes << "#{opts.delete(:color)} " if opts[:color]

  size = opts.delete(:size)
  additional_classes << "#{size} " if !!size

  flipped_direction = opts.delete(:flipped)
  additional_classes << "#{flipped_direction} flipped" if !!flipped_direction

  rotated_direction = opts.delete(:rotated)
  additional_classes << "#{rotated_direction} rotated" if !!rotated_direction

  opts[:class] = "#{opts[:class]} #{additional_classes} #{icon_name} icon"

  content_tag(:i, '', opts)
end
```

Comment: What's happening within your method? As I've tried running your code as-is and it works without error in ruby 2.3.0 on my machine.

Comment: I've updated the question... also I tried defining a method like so in the rails console and I didn't get this error message...

Comment: Aahhhh! Never mind! I am such an idiot. The problem is caused by a method from a gem that has a helper with the exact same name, not by my function... Thanks and sorry everyone!

Comment: `font-awesome-(less/sass)`?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately... :-)

Comment: I use `font-awesome-rails`. Think it was available before the official gems. The helper in that one is `fa_icon`, so you wouldn't have a conflict there.

Comment: Yeah... it's fine, thanks! I'll rename the method - that's ok. I'm just happy that I understood the whole thing :-)

Answer (score 0):

With your original method definition, just try wrapping your options hash in curly braces:

```
icon(:info, {class: 'info-popup', data: { content: 'content', variation: 'inverted' }})
```

Comment: Oh, forgot that... I tried that as well, also resulting in `unknown keywords: class, data` --> I don't get it

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in second approach. Named parameters should be declared with double splat, not with `*+`:

```
 ▶ def icon(icon_name, **opts) ; puts opts.inspect ; end
 #⇒ :icon
 ▶ icon :info, class: 'info-popup', 
               data: { content: 'content', variation: 'inverted' })
 #⇒ {:class=>"info-popup", 
 #⇒  :data=>{:content=>"content", :variation=>"inverted"}}
```

Comment: Tried that as well, still resulting in `unknown keywords: class, data`